# User friendly URLS .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I have the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/([^/]*) fishery.php?url=$2&region=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*) region.php?region=$1 [L]
```

when i type in domain.com/fishing/fife then it displays the proper region.php file.

however if i type in domain.com/fishing/fife/ with the / at the end then it loads the fishery.php page instead. How can i prevent this?

Secondly is it bad for SEO purposes if it loads as /fishing/fife instead of fishing/fife.php ?? After all its a page not a directory? If it doesnt matter then i would much prefer it not to have the .php as it looks alot tidier.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/([^/]+) fishery.php?url=$2&region=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/?$ region.php?region=$1 [L]
```

Also there's nothing wrong with having a "directory" url instead of a page, infact I think this might be better not worse for SEO...

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. This worked perfect. Could i trouble you for an explanation? also any advise on the second part?

Comment: I changed the `*` into a `+` (in the first pattern) as `+` means 1-or-more (`*` means 0-or-more) so it will no longer match if there's nothing after the second slash.  For the second pattern I put a `/?` (`?` means 0-or-one of the preceding char) so it matches a `/` at the end if it's there and then a `$`  which just means the end of the url, it's not really necessary in this case but I find it good practice to signify where the end of the url is in the pattern to avoid unexpected pattern conflicts

Comment: Thanks once again for your help.